# Use of who not directly after subject

Tags: who

My question is about using 'who' in a sentence. Compare,

> ...particularly children who are vulnerable...

vs.

> ...particularly children in Germany who are vulnerable..

Is the second sentence grammatically correct, even though 'who' is not directly placed next to the subject?

Comment: But ***who*** IS directly placed next to the subject! In this case the subject is the compound noun phrase ***children in Germany***. The only issue is whether what follows is a *restrictive* relative clause or not (is it mentioning in passing that *all* children in Germany are vulnerable, or specifically restricting the statement to those who *are* vulnerable?).

Comment: You know your context, but you haven't told *us* that. I'm sure there are far more than 10,000 German "children" in total, and they're probably all "vulnerable" to certain things. Note that *vulnerable to X* doesn't mean *has experienced X* - it means ***might feasibly experience X***.

Comment: You're dribbling out fragments of the full context in comments, when they should be in the question (which I'm sure should be on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) anyway, not here). There's no particular limit on how long a noun phrase can be - providing the entire sequence of words *collectively* functions syntactically as a noun, it's an NP.

Comment: I am not learning English. I had a question on the general use of who and wanted to be very precise. You asked me about the context and I provided it for YOU only. I would have been fine otherwise. Time to delete this lengthy chat.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What exactly is the Subject in that sentence. I can't see it.

Comment: @Araucaria: Despite the fact that OP calls them "sentences", they're obviously *not*. They're just *clauses* that contain neither a subject nor the associated verb. As OP points out, he's not learning English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, so there's no subjects or lions around in that fragment ;) But your comment's got two upvotes. Could you delete it. Please?

Comment: @Araucaria: Lions? I think we're talking about *refugee children* in modern Germany, not Christians in ancient Rome.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yep, no lions, Subjects, extrapositions or penguins.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Or carrots either.

Comment: They are sentences truncated by ellipsis --use your imagination and subsume your answer. If I had been more specific and provided the a random example, my question would be more suitable for the English Language Learners SE. I asked a question about general grammar (remembering my teacher that was saying it is bad practice to have a 'who' not immediately next to the subject) and the accepted answer has been very helpful to finish my article. There I have many instances of this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. "Children in Germany" is a [noun phrase](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/nounphrase.htm) with *children* as the head word. The word *who* still refers to the *children* in the second version.

Comment: Yes. If one said *particularly children who, in Germany, are vulnerable* it would mean almost the same thing, but perhaps add emphasis to the fact that it only affected *children in Germany*.

Comment: That's a great comment. It adds more scope to my writing, thanks!

Comment: *Children in Germany* isn't a phrasal noun old bean. It's just a noun phrase. There's nothing idiomatic there, it's a straightforward noun being modified by a preposition phrase :(

Comment: I rather hastily downvoted you, which I don't think I wanted to do. If you edited a full stop (or changed *phrasal noun* to *noun phrase*) I'd be able to undo my vote - which is currently locked in (so I can't undo it unless there's an edit)

Comment: @Araucaria I've changed *phrasal noun* to *noun phrase*, which I prefer anyway. Thanks for letting me know. :)